# 3D Cursor Rotation?

Tags: 3d-cursor

I thought the 3D cursor was pretty lame when I first started using Blender - another strange thing Blender was doing differently than every other program. But it seems like I find a new use for it every couple days. I noticed recently that it appears to have a rotation state (I'm using 2.8 in case it is a recent change).

What I'm wondering is why Blender doesn't make use of that rotation when I use the "cursor to selected" or "selection to cursor" commands. It only seems to change the object or cursor's position, leaving rotation as-is.

If these commands made use of rotation, we could then set our transformation orientation mode to cursor, and instantly have custom orientation modes within a few clicks. For example, you could select a character's eyeball, choose cursor to selected, set the orientation mode to cursor, then move some object or component, relative to their line of sight (G, Z, 10).

My question - is there a way to upgrade the cursor or enable a higher level cursor mode? Something that makes use of the cursor rotation state? If not, why does it have a rotation state?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean **object's** rotation in accordance with the cursor's position? I think it could be scripted. For the sake of clarity, where did you see it? Give links/images.

Comment: In 2.8, if you select View tab on the [N] panel, you can see the cursor's rotation state near the bottom, under the 3D Cursor section.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the <kbd>N</kbd> properties region of the 3D view, there is a 'Tool' tab for the options of your current tool. If you are using the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> > <kbd>Space</kbd> 3D cursor tool, you are given options for orientation.

[image]

Here, by setting the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> Creation > 'Align' option to '3D Cursor', a cube has been created aligned to the face of another object.

Edit.. as far as I can see....:

I haven't found a *direct* way to align the cursor to the transformation of an object or bone.  However, you can do it in 2 steps:

- Use the '+' at the top right of the header's Orientation panel to create a Custom Transform Orientation from your: object in Object Mode, components of your object or armature in Edit Mode, or bone in Pose Mode.
- Use the 3D Cursor tool as before, with its 'Orientation' option set to 'Transform'.

This isn't *too* onerous, the 3DC setting is sticky: it persists after first use in each mode.

You can set up a Quick Menu item or keyboard shortcut for the creation of the Custom Orientation by right-clicking the '+'. AFAIK you will have to do this once for each of the modes: Object/Edit/Pose. You can set the Custom Orientation to be used immediately after creation, and/or overwrite the last-created one.

As for <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> snapping, the cursor does not automatically adopt the orientation when snapped. It had to be dragged a little in the viewport to take up the orientation before snapping.

You can always align an object to a transform orientation by using the Header menu > Object > Transform > 'Align to Transform Orientation' , and you can crate a shortcut for that, too.

Comment: ..although, to tell the truth, I still generally prefer using Custom Orientations.. and have had to replace the old keyboard shortcut to  make them quickly...

Comment: Noticed the other day setting `scene.cursor.matrix` does nought. Is there a setting such that  snap cursor to active, in object mode, sets cursor to the active object matrix_world?

Comment: This is very close to what I was hoping for, but unfortunately armature bones don't have surfaces that relate well to their orientation. Is there a way to align the cursor to the object's transform instead of its surface? I guess this still wouldn't let me make use of that rotation when I use Selection to Cursor. Thanks for the helpful information!

Comment: @batFINGER, see edit... is this area, umm.. 'unfinished'?

Comment: @Robert, see edit. I find 'Create Custom Orientation' a strange candidate for removal from the standard keymap.. but there it is..

Comment: My original intention was to use the cursor logic as a temporary custom orientation, so I wouldn't need to constantly create custom orientations for bones. My bone transforms constantly change, so I'm forced to delete and recreate my custom orientations, which becomes tedious after a while. Still, I appreciate your effort to provide a mechanism that helps. Might be a good candidate for future improvements to Blender. The selection <-> cursor tools are very helpful for positioning elements, relatively, but I think including rotations would make it better. Maybe with a toggle to disable it.

Comment: @Robert totally agree. The 3D cursor still seems an incomplete tool . the creation of temporary orientations / manipulation of object pivots is, IMO, a lot quicker and more intuitive in .. well.. at least 3DS and XSI, which are the ones I know about ..

Comment: On unfinished... I hope so.   the pre-drag snaps (good get btw) but  inconsistently. Setting cursor rot-mode to quaternion worked on occasion too.  As with OP my expectation is in transform mode it would take on the global  transform of the object.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I've found is:

1. Align 3D cursor to the object you want to duplicate rotation to
   (select object -> shift+S -> Cursor to selected).
2. Select the target object that needs to be aligned to 3D cursor.
3. Menu - Object -> Transform -> Align to Transform Orientation
4. Left-bottom menu of the screen -> transform orientation to 3D Cursor -> and select axis you'd like.
5. You are welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you enter the `View` tab from the Sidebar (by pressing press <kbd>N</kbd>), there is a [`3D Cursor` section](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/sidebar.html?highlight=sidebar#d-cursor) where you can set the cursor rotation.

[image]